# How to skip scheduled call to a method when an asynchronous task is ongoing on that method itself?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, nstimer

Suppose I have a method that does some asynchronous tasks. Let's say it refreshes user's access permission and it may take several minutes depending on the internet connection speed or whatever.

I have to call this method periodically (i.e. scheduled call using `NSTimer`'s method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target: selector: userInfo: repeats:`)

```
-(void)refreshPermission {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // do something that takes a few minutes
    });
}
```

Now I call this method as `timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(refreshPermission) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`. That is, this call is fired every 10 seconds.

> What I need to do is, I need to somehow skip one (or, more than one)
>   scheduled call to this method **if something is happening inside that
>   asynchronous block** (*Let's say, user's access permission hasn't been
>   updated*).

But once the block is done (*that is, user's access permission has been updated*), **scheduled call with timer should resume.**

Any idea or any sample on how to accomplish this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this approach. Got the idea from @Sunny's answer.

It worked for me. But any suggestion regarding this implementation is appreciated.

```
-(void)refresh {
    NSLog(@"Refresh called");
    NSLock *theLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"Async task assigned");

        if(!isExecuting){

            [theLock lock];
            isExecuting = YES;
            [theLock unlock];

            // Perform your tasks
            NSLog(@"Async task started");
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 13.0];  // for testing purpose
            NSLog(@"Async task completed");

            [theLock lock];
            isExecuting = NO;
            [theLock unlock];

        }
    });
}
```

Here `isExecuting` is an instance variable of the containing class. And it was set to `isExecuting = NO;` before setting the actual scheduled timer for calling the method periodically.

Here I used `NSLock` for the assurance that no other thread can change the value of `isExecuting` while a thread is in execution of it's task. I added this locking because every time `-(void)refresh` method is invoked, there is a possibility that multiple threads become eligible for the execution and changing value of `isExecuting`. So it's better to make it thread save when changing value of shared variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by using a `Bool` variable. You can declare `Bool` variable globally and by using its state you can manage your task in function call.

In method `refreshPermission`

```
-(void)refreshPermission {
   if(!isExecuting){

      isExecuting = YES;
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Perform your tasks

         isExecuting = NO;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's clever. But checking and setting bool to YES should be done before the `dispatch_async` block as I think. Right?

Comment: But does it gurantee **setting `isExecuting = NO` inside the `dispatch_async` block will happen after completion of the task**?

Comment: Previous one was the one that I was looking for. I've changed the implementation slightly to make it thread safe. You can have a look